Unbound Identifier Racket
#lang racket

(define-syntax unpack
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(unpack) (begin (define x 1))]))

(unpack)

(+ x 1)

Why is it that I am getting an error: x: unbound identifier in: x?
After defining the macro, I expect the code to define x appropriate w/o error? I can't seem to figure this out, could it be an issue with the syntax or compiler?

Macro hygiene.  The symbol x in the macro expansion is not the same symbol as the one in the following expression.

The macro expander intentionally works this way to avoid accidentally interfering with the x in the outer context.
One way to tell the expander you actually want to use the outer x is to pass it in.
(define-syntax unpack
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ id) (begin (define id 1))]))

(unpack x)

Another way is to use datum->syntax to construct an identifier x in the same context in which the usage of unpack appears.
(define-syntax (unpack stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(k)
     (with-syntax ([id (datum->syntax #'k 'x)])
       #'(begin (define id 1)))]))

(unpack)


I see! I was under the impression that the macro would directly replace the code and didn't know that I would have to directly pass the outer x. I see that it is the result of hygienic macros, thanks for the link!!
